# How do I create a drawable for my custom separator?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a separator line in my android view.  The setup I want is for the drawable to be 2px tall and width set to fill_parent, with the bottom 1px being a white line and the top 1px being a black line with an alpha component. It seems like this should be possible with layer-list using an offset, but, as the documentation warned, the view starts scaling all of the items and then the blending messes up the delineation.

I have this working using a png and scaling and it looks alright on my test device and emulator, just thought it would make more sense to define it explicitly in xml rather than making a custom png for every type of separator. An

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a [ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html)? You can define it in XML and use as you would a png.

Comment: I tried that, i suppose I could make two separate ShapeDrawables, it just seemed excessive to have two image views to display the two shapedrawables instead of just building a single drawable.